# Google Maps Mod pre-purchase question

Tags: add-on, google-maps-for-ee, objective-html

I am creating a business directory and want to have a map that shows locations of member businesses.

Can I use the fieldtype to allow members to show location of their business, then display a map that show all locations from ALL entries in the member channel?

Can I restrict the fieldtype so that a member can only place one marker?

I also need to assign categories to each entry and then have either a drop menu or check boxes that allow for filtering. So the user can display only locations that match a certain category.

Also, can you get the entry_url to be a link in the info box?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps can do all of this, yes (and makes it really easy). It's a very flexible add-on. Sorry for the short answer, but it really just is "yes" to each of your questions. :-)

By the way, this isn't an official response since obviously I'm just a user, not the developer of this add-on. But my guess is that Justin would agree. ;-)

Comment: Yup, Alex is correct. These are all very straightforward requests and all included with Google Maps for EE. Just email support@objectivehtml.com if anyone has any specific questions.